# pthread_mutex_lock return not tested

Tags: multithreading, coding-style, pthreads

I'm really wondering why all source codes that implement a 
**pthread_mutex_lock** never test its return value as defined :

[documentation of pthread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

even in books the examples don't test if the lock is in error, codes just do the  lock.

Is there any reason I missed to let it untested ?

Comment: See the rationale for TSan's `ReportTypeMutexInvalidAccess` at https://reviews.llvm.org/D18132?id=50550. It's true nobody checks the return code, and so there is TSan for the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the only “interesting” error is `EINVAL`, which in most programs will only happen because of memory corruption, or, as I know from my own painful experience, during program shutdown after destructors have already destroyed some mutexes. The way I see it, the only reasonable response to such an error is to abort the program, which on the other hand is very inconvenient if the errors occur precisely because the program is already shutting down. Of course, this can be solved, but it’s not at all that simple, and not much is gained by it for most programs.

Comment: Then you don't handle mem corruption ?

Comment: No, you don't "handle" memory corruption, you just don't corrupt memory in the first place.

Comment: Actually, my question was more about EBUSY or EDEADLK, respectively : 
"The mutex could not be acquired because it was already locked"  and "A deadlock condition was detected or the current thread already owns the mutex": what make you think this can't happen ?

Comment: EBUSY is not a documented error condition of pthread_mutex_lock, while EDEADLK does only happen if you have explicitly set the mutex' type to error checking (PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK).

Comment: +1 for calling out the uselessness of "tinfoil hat programming".

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think "all source code" and "never test" are too strong. I think "some" and "often" would be more accurate.

In books, error checking code is often omitted for clarity of exposition.

As to real-world code, I guess the answer has to be that it is perceived that the likelihood of failure is very low. Whether this is a good assumption is debatable.

Comment: I agree on the form I don't for the substance as "some" and "often" are subjective ideas too. What I meant is that "most" of the time the code and provided examples are not including return for that kind of function